# How to order by a property in a collection using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a link sequence, and I want to order by User.Name (its a sequence of users).

How can I do that?

Also, if I want to remove any users with User.Count = 0 can I do that in the same query?

Answer (score 10):

```
IEnumerable<User> result = from user in users
                           where user.Count != 0
                           orderby user.Name
                           select user;
```

or

```
IEnumerable<User> result = users.Where(user => user.Count != 0)
                                .OrderBy(user => user.Name);
```

where `users` is a IEnumerable<User> (such as a List<User>).

This selects all users where `user.Count != 0` and returns them ordered by `user.Name`.

Note that the original collection `users` remains unchanged.

Comment: also check other overload version of OrderBy if you want to implement your own Comparer.